# Refreshing View with Hibernate

Tags: wicket

I set up a refreshing view, which adds items using hibernate, but I can't get it to update after I press submit, here is the refreshing view:

```
   public class ListViewPanel extends Panel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

final List<IModel<UserDetails>> users = new ArrayList<IModel<UserDetails>>();

public ListViewPanel(String id, IModel<?> model) {
    super(id, model);

    Test test = new Test();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = test.configureSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    listUsers(session, users);

    add(new RefreshingView<UserDetails>("users") {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected Iterator getItemModels() {

            return users.iterator();
        }

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(Item<UserDetails> item) {

            UserDetails user = item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("userName", user.getUserName()));
            item.add(new Label("userAddress", user.getAddress()));
        }

    });

}

public void listUsers(Session session, List<IModel<UserDetails>> users) {

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserDetails.class);
    for (Object i : criteria.list()) {

        users.add(Model.of((UserDetails) i));
    }

}
```

So then I add my list view panel to my HomePage:

```
   add(usersView = new ListViewPanel("users", null));
```

Then in my OnSubmit button I try to call a new model object

```
   usersView.getDefaultModelObject();
```

The data is being added to hibernate because each time I run the application, the ListViewPanel displays the new entries, but they are not updated while the program is running.

Comment: getDefaultModelObject provides the object for the IModel which is coupled with a certain component (Panel, Page). In your case ListViewPanel doesn't have a coupled IModel (you even set this to null), so nothing happens.

Comment: Hi, when I set it to `usersView = new ListViewPanel("users", Model.of(getDefaultModel()));` it still provides no update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the Model concept of Wicket. getDefaultModel() is providing the model bound to some component (page, panel, ...). You are responsible to provide the data.

In your case, wrap the data in `LoadableDetachableModel<UserDetails>` and provide the model istance to the `RefreshingView<UserDetails>`.

If you are submitting the form with ajax, than add the `ListViewPanel` to `AjaxRequestTarget` (This marks components which need to be repainted).